# Effort + Autofac : did not return an object that inherits from DbProviderServices

Tags: entity-framework, autofac, effort, entity-framework-6.2

I'm using `Effort`, `Effort.EF6` as my In-Memory database to test my `Web API 2` application.

I'm using `Autofac` for my DI resolve.

This is my code in `Startup.cs`

```
builder.Register(c =>
                {
                    var dbConnectionFactory =
                        Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePersistent(nameof(CvManagementDbContext));
                    return new CvManagementDbContext(dbConnectionFactory);
                })
                .As<DbContext>()
                .SingleInstance();
```

And in my `CvManagementDbContext.cs`:

```
public CvManagementDbContext(DbConnection connection)
            : base(connection, true)
        {
        }
```

**[UPDATE]**

This is my `package.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="ApiMultipartFormDataFormatter" version="1.0.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Autofac" version="4.8.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Autofac.WebApi2" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="AutoMapper" version="7.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="AutoMapper.EF6" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="DelegateDecompiler" version="0.24.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="DelegateDecompiler.EntityFramework" version="0.24.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Effort" version="1.3.10" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Effort.EF6" version="1.3.10" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="JWT" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.2.6" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.6" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.6" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.6" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" version="5.2.6" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" version="5.2.6" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.6" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="2.9.0" targetFramework="net46" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Mono.Reflection" version="1.1.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Mono.Reflection.Core" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="NMemory" version="2.0.4" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Common" version="5.4.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Interfaces" version="5.4.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Redis" version="5.4.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Text" version="5.4.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net46" />
</packages>
```

The configuration of Effort in `Web.config`

```
<entityFramework>
    <interceptors>
      <interceptor type="Cv_Management.Interceptor.GlobalDbCommandInterceptor, Cv_Management" />
    </interceptors>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <!--<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />-->
      <provider invariantName="Effort.Provider" type="Effort.Provider.EffortProviderServices,Effort" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

When my application starts an exception thrown in the console, which is :

> **'The 'Instance' member of the Entity Framework provider type 'Effort.Provider.EffortProviderServices, Effort, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6a46696d54971e6d' did not return an object that inherits from 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices'. Entity Framework providers must inherit from this class and the 'Instance' member must return the singleton instance of the provider. This may be because the provider does not support Entity Framework 6 or later; see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.'**

What wrong am I doing ?

Comment: Could you add your packages.config, sections of web.config with EF settings? And check reference to Effort, whether it points to correct version of Effort.

Comment: I have updated my `package.config` file on my question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I managed to reproduced your issue. You see `Effort` and `Effort.EF6` are mutually exclusive libraries, you only one of them. According to Effort [github](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Effort/wiki/NuGet-Packages):

> **If you use Entity Framework 6...**
>
> - You will need the Effort.EF6 package
> - Check the offical NuGet site
>
> **otherwise...**
>
> - You will need the Effort package
> - Check the offical NuGet site

I got your error when I have reference to dll from `Effort` package in my csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="Effort, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6a46696d54971e6d, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Effort.1.3.10\lib\net45\Effort.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

The error is gone when I have changed reference to dll from `Effort.EF6` package:

```
<Reference Include="Effort, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6a46696d54971e6d, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Effort.EF6.1.3.10\lib\net45\Effort.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Check references in your csproj file, make sure, that you use dll from `Effort.EF6`. And get rid of `Effort` package. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
By changing to Effor.EF6. It worked. 
I think this is the library issue :(.

Comment: Happt to help=)